I have attu ForbiddenError and don't know if i should set user
I can't access milvus attu. ForbiddenError.
and I was using attu 2.3.2 and then upgraded to attu 2.4.2.
I haven't set anything like User, Role, etc.
here is the error:
 POST 200 /api/v1/milvus/connect 154.498 ms @ ...
GET /api/v1/users 403 ForbiddenError: Can not find your connection, please check your connection settings.
 GET 403 /api/v1/users 0.579 ms ...
 GET 304 /api/v1/milvus/version 0.368 ms ...

My question is do I need to set user?
But, when connecting with pymilvus client, it connects without any authentication such as user, token, password, etc.
Thanks!

please upgrade your attu to the latest version.  https://github.com/zilliztech/attu

Based on the information provided, it appears that the issue may be related to a connection or authentication problem with Milvus. First, ensure that you are using Attu version 2.4.x, as it is compatible with Milvus 2.4. If you encounter a 403 ForbiddenError when attempting to get Milvus user info, it could indicate a connection loss or authentication failure. To resolve this, try restarting your Attu container, as this may re-establish the connection and resolve the authentication request failure.
